# iOS navigation issue: after pushing a ViewController, it results in a navigation bar showing the navigation items of the previous ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

This situation happens very rarely and I don't know how to reproduce it, but it does happen sometimes and I would like to fix it.

In `ViewController A`, if I push `ViewController B`in, sometimes(not always) when `ViewController B` did appear, the navigation bar is showing the navigation bar items of `ViewController A`, not those of `ViewController B`. If I click on the back button, I cannot go back to `ViewController A`, getting stuck in `ViewController B`.

A `UIBarButtonItem` is added to the navigation items of `ViewController A`, and the navigation items of `ViewController A` will be updated in response to some events. Is it the reason that causes this issue?

**Codes for pushing `ViewController B`**

```
ViewControllerB* viewControllerB = [ViewControllerB new];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
```

**Codes for updating the navigation items in `ViewController A`**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if(NumberOfCalendarOperations == 0){
        [self showNavigatorBarButtons];
    }
    else{
        [self startRefreshAnimationOnUpdateButton];
    }
}



//This method is triggered through notification when the number of operations in   calendarOperationQueue is changed

-(void)calendarOperationQueueStateDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification{
    if(NumberOfCalendarOperations == 0){

        if (self.isShowActivityIndicator) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self showNavigatorBarButtons];
            });
        }
    }
    else{
        if (!self.isShowActivityIndicator) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self startRefreshAnimationOnUpdateButton];
            });
        }
    }
}
```

/**
 * Show the update button on the right of navigation bar
 */

```
-(void)showNavigatorBarButtons{
    self.isShowActivityIndicator = NO;
    UIBarButtonItem *updateButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sync.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(updateButtonDidPress:)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:updateButton, nil]];}
```

/**
 * Start refresh animation on the update button
 */

```
-(void)startRefreshAnimationOnUpdateButton{

    if (self.navigationController.topViewController != self) {
        return;
    }
    self.isShowActivityIndicator = YES;

    UIView* updateButtonView = nil;

    for (UIView *subViewInNavigationBar in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews){

    NSString *subViewClassAsString = NSStringFromClass([subViewInNavigationBar class]);

        if ([subViewClassAsString compare:@"UINavigationButton" /* TODO: be careful with this */
                              options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame){

        if ([subViewInNavigationBar isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] == YES){

                if(updateButtonView == nil){
                    updateButtonView = subViewInNavigationBar;
                }
                else if(subViewInNavigationBar.center.x < updateButtonView.center.x){
                    updateButtonView = subViewInNavigationBar;
                }

        }

        }

    }

    for (UIView *subViewsInButton in updateButtonView.subviews){

        if ([subViewsInButton isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] == YES &&
            subViewsInButton.frame.origin.x != 0.0f &&
            subViewsInButton.frame.origin.y != 0.0f){

            [subViewsInButton removeFromSuperview];


            CGRect activityIndicatorFrame = self.updateButtonActivityIndicator.frame;
            activityIndicatorFrame.origin.x = (CGRectGetWidth(updateButtonView.frame) / 2.0f) - (CGRectGetWidth(activityIndicatorFrame) / 2.0f);
            activityIndicatorFrame.origin.y = (CGRectGetHeight(updateButtonView.frame) / 2.0f) - (CGRectGetHeight(activityIndicatorFrame) / 2.0f);
            self.updateButtonActivityIndicator.frame = activityIndicatorFrame;

            [self.updateButtonActivityIndicator startAnimating];

            [updateButtonView addSubview:self.updateButtonActivityIndicator];

            return;

        }

    }

}
```

Anyone has got a clue? Thank you.

Comment: How have you added the bar buttons in ViewControllerA??

Comment: Yes, a UIBarButtonItem is added to the navigation items of A, and the navigation items of A will be updated in response to some events.

Comment: I mean have you added the bar buttons in ViewController A itself??

Comment: Yes, I added a UIBarButtonItem on the right of the bar in ViewController A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the reason of this issue. It is that I try to hide the navigation bar in `viewWillDisappear`. Now iOS allows me to back to the previous view by panning from the left edge of the screen. But while panning from the left edge, if I cancel this action, and pan back to the left edge, the navigation bar will enter this strange state.